# Round trip WinForms binding with formatting enabled. MVVM

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm

I'd like to have a two way binding work round trip while practicing MVVM. For example

1. Value is updated in view.
2. View model property receives value through binding.
3. View model property augments value and raises property change event.
4. View receives changed value.

Example in code:

Binding in view:

```
Binding numBind = new Binding(nameof(textBox.Text), _vm, nameof(_vm.Num), true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
numBind.Format += (sender, e) => { e.Value = e.Value.ToString(); };
numBind.Parse += (sender, e) => { e.Value = float.Parse(e.Value.ToString()); };
textBox.DataBindings.Add(numBind);
```

Property in View Model

```
public float Num
{
    get
    {
        return _num;
    }
    set
    {
        _num = value + 1;
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Num));
    }
}
```

Attempting this resulted in my view and view model having different values. After looking at Microsoft's source with a college, it appears that the true format flag is preventing the round trip from occurring. If this is truly the case, perhaps they are attempting to minimize performance setbacks of formatting?

Note: The View Model cannot have any knowledge of the View, so I don't believe I can force the value to update.

Comment: What is `PropChangeEventHere()`? Does your view model implement `INPC` or ?

Comment: @NicholasAndre If your view model raises the correct property changed notification, the text box is reflecting it correctly with the posted setup. Do you have a repro?

Comment: @IvanStoev Correct. Updates from the vm propagate to the view properly. Unfortunately, I cannot share the full example/context. :/ If there is any information you need please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Well, all we need is a [mcve]. E.g. sample (but full) `ViewModel` class (with single `Text` property), sample `View` with data binding. Actually I've created a quick test, and with what you have posted, when I type something in the text box, it updates the view model, which in turn reflects the modification back to the view. So simply the case is not reproducible.

Comment: @IvanStoev A colleague of mine took a look at the binding source code and found that format flag was causing the issue. You should be able to reproduce this issue if you set the format parameter to true. I will update my question's example to show the issue.

Comment: To be honest, I did that before posting my previous comment. But in your sample it was set to `false`, that's why I said its not reproducible. What about `FormattingEnabled` flag, it's supposed to fix some old buggy behaviors and normally should be set to `true`, but not in this specific case :) Probably `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` is not appropriate for `TextBox` like editors - we usually use it only for checkbox and combobox editors. Anyway, to recap, some behavior are broken in WF. But playing with modes and flags can produce what you need.